# Any way to export Xamarin.Forms app so that I can call from Android Studio Java App?

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.forms application that is a photo taking app. I would like to export this as an aar or something that I can then share with some other developers so that they can bring it into their existing applications and make a call to it as an intent or whatever other solution might be possible.  Can this be done?

Essentially we have devs that are not familiar with Xamarin but are with Java in Android Studio. So I am trying to figure out the easiest way for them to use my implementation in their app to take a photo and then handle the result as they wish.

If anyone has any insight, I would love to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Jason!  Think this is the same as well. Will check it out.